# Where do I save my pictures in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am currently saving my pictures in Visual Studio in an asset folder:

```
C:\Users\patrick\source\repos\WpfRecon\WpfRecon\Assets\BackGround.png
```

When a "user" downloads from Github it won't work as it won't be in this directory location, due to name and if they have changed the defaults on the installation of Visual Studios.

How can I reference the pictures in my project to be generic enough so that there are no installations or customizations required to run my applications?

--Code snippet--

```
.Image gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="C:\Users\patrick\source\repos\WpfRecon\WpfRecon\Assets\BackGround.gif" x:Name="Gif" Margin="0,0,-36.333,0" Grid.RowSpan="6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="C:\Users\patrick\source\repos\WpfRecon\WpfRecon\Assets\BackGround.gif" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="800" Stretch="Fill"/><Image gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="C:\Users\patrick\source\repos\WpfRecon\WpfRecon\Assets\BackGround.gif" x:Name="Gif" Margin="0,0,-36.333,0" Grid.RowSpan="6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="C:\Users\patrick\source\repos\WpfRecon\WpfRecon\Assets\BackGround.gif" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="800" Stretch="Fill"/>"
```

Comment: upload them to a server and link to the server.

Comment: `How can i reference the pictures in my project` Step one - show us a [mcve] that shows us how you are referencing pictures **now**.

Comment: Valid point but not an option as this is an offline WPF application that pings (later port scans) a local LAN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are using absolute path `C:\Users\patrick\source\repos\WpfRecon\WpfRecon\Assets\BackGround.png`.  You should use relative pathing so that the name does not matter, for example: `../Assets/BackGround.png`

Comment: It has come up with the following errors:Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\patrick.wake\source\repos\WpfRecon\WpfRecon\Assets\BackGround.gif'. WpfRecon About.xaml 13

Comment: also this oneSeverity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  Could not find file 'C:\Windows\system32\..%5CAssets%5CBackGround.gif'. WpfRecon MainPage.xaml 27

Comment: take a look at [what is relative path](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
var dir = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(
                              Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), 
                              @"Initializer\Files\");
```

Comment: Not sure i can do this in WPF C#